# Jquery Prevent shortcuts when input in focus

Tags: jquery, input, keyboard-shortcuts

I add shortcuts to my web app, but I want to stop them when input is infocus...

```
$(function () {
    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.charCode);
        switch (ch) {
            case 'p': case 'P':
                mainMenuRegulations();
                break;
            case 's': case 'S':
                mainMenuJurisprudence();
                break;
            case 'm': case 'M':
                mainMenuModels()
                break;
            case 'i': case 'I':
                showImprintContact();
                break;
}
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the currently active element (focused element) is an input inside the keypress event handler :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keypress', function(event) {

        if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ) {

            var ch = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

            switch (ch) {
                // your code here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

To be even more specific, you could check the `document.activeElement` type as well, and check for text, number or whatever else you're using ?